# ColorBitmap is used by other subprocess

Tags: c#, bitmap, subprocess, kinect

I'm using C# and my code is the following. I know that is not very optimized, but I only need help with solving this issue.

```
internal class ImageProcessing
{
    private KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;
    private ColorFrameReader colorFrameReader = null;
    private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap = null;
    private Mat frame = null;
    private int verify = 0;
    public Mat ObjectRec(Mat Object)
    {
        long i;
        ObjectRecog();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ImageSource();

            return ImageProcessingExt.RecogObject.Draw(Object, this.frame, out i);

    }
    public void ObjectRecog()
    {
        // get the kinectSensor object
        this.kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

        // open the reader for the color frames
        this.colorFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.ColorFrameSource.OpenReader();

        // wire handler for frame arrival
        this.colorFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_ColorFrameArrived;

        // create the colorFrameDescription from the ColorFrameSource using Bgra format
        FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = this.kinectSensor.ColorFrameSource.CreateFrameDescription(ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

        // create the bitmap to display
        this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorFrameDescription.Width, colorFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

        // set IsAvailableChanged event notifier
        this.kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += this.Sensor_IsAvailableChanged;

        // open the sensor
        this.kinectSensor.Open();

    }

    private void Reader_ColorFrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)

        {
                // ColorFrame is IDisposable
                using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
                {
                    if (colorFrame != null)
                    {
                        FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;

                        using (KinectBuffer colorBuffer = colorFrame.LockRawImageBuffer())
                        {

                            this.colorBitmap.Lock();

                            // verify data and write the new color frame data to the display bitmap
                            if ((colorFrameDescription.Width == this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth) && (colorFrameDescription.Height == this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight))
                            {
                                colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToIntPtr(
                                    this.colorBitmap.BackBuffer,
                                    (uint)(colorFrameDescription.Width * colorFrameDescription.Height * 4),
                                    ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

                                this.colorBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight));
                            }
                        }
                        this.colorBitmap.Unlock();

                    }

            }


    }
    private void Sensor_IsAvailableChanged(object sender, IsAvailableChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    public System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap image1
    {
        get{
            return this.colorBitmap;
            }
    }
    public void ImageSource()
    {
        WriteableBitmap astreisco = image1;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> image;
        Bitmap pene;
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)astreisco));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        pene = new Bitmap(outStream);
        image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(pene);
        this.frame = image.Mat;
        verify = 1;
    }
}
```

}

I get the error at **this.colorBitmap.Lock();**, and it says that another subprocess is using that colorBitap. I've tried a lot of things, but no one worked.

The Kinect code is copied from MSDN.

Comment: Are you using thread???? Also, where's the `Main` function???